# GCC cross-compiler for a freestanding environemnt, "__float128 is not suppported for this target" is reported as an error when you include <cstddef>

Tags: c++, gcc, freestanding

When building GCC cross-compiler (C++) for a freestanding environemnt, "__float128 is not suppported for this target" is reported as an error when you include .

When building GCC cross-compiler for a freestanding environemnt, "__float128 is not suppported for this target" is reported as an error when you include .
How can you eliminate this error

I built and configured the the GCC cross-compiler like so

```
export PREFIX="$PWD/opt/cross"
export TARGET=i686-elf
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"

# Configure, build, and install the GCC cross-compiler
git clone git://gcc.gnu.org/git/gcc.git gcc
mkdir build-gcc
cd build-gcc
../gcc/configure --target=$TARGET -- prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers --disable-hosted-libstdcxx
make all-gcc
make all-target-libgcc
make all-target-libstdc++-v3
make install-gcc
make install-target-libstdc++-v3
```

And when I try to include `#include <cstddef>`, I get the following error

```
In included file: __float128 is not supprted on this target
```

[image: Error]

Note: I should add that my program compiles just fine. Even with all warnings turned on.

Comment: which platform are you compiling for? [*`__float128` is available on i386, x86_64, IA-64, and hppa HP-UX, as well as on PowerPC GNU/Linux targets that enable the vector scalar (VSX) instruction set.*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html)

Comment: @phuclv I'm targeting i686. But it's qemu and virtualized. Is there a way to disable the warning? Maybe edit the c++config.h?